# How can I efficiently load huge volumes of star systems?

Tags: unity, architecture, performance, databases, loading

I am working on a space exploration and combat game, and I can create galaxies, nebulas, solar systems, and load and unload them procedurally as needed. Meaning the stars that the player can see are exactly where they are. I have a coordinate system set up with meter-precision, meaning it's sufficient to map quite several galaxies, but also tiny missiles.

For now, I created a galaxy with 10.000.000 solar systems, and my SQLite database reached 5gb. It takes ~30 minutes to generate it, and I notice a slow-down as the size of the database increases in loading times. I did a lot of optimization, and while everything is running fine and well now, I seek to reach 200-300m solar systems if possible. The database would be stored locally on the user's drive, rather than downloaded from a server. I use a GlobalX/Y/Z (int64) and LocalX/Y/Z (double) for coordinates, and only the GlobalX/Y/Z is used to find large objects like stars and planets (I also use multiple chunk systems).

[Elite Dangerous manages to store the data of 400 *billion*](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy) solar systems and has no issues with loading times, somehow. How can they display many stars in the background? How do they manage to store a lot more data than I already do?

For now, my data is quite minimalistic and comparatively minuscule in number, but they must have quite a lot of data for each stellar object even. What technical "tricks" can I employ to solve this problem in my game?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/55u07s/what_exactly_in_this_game_is_procedurally/ good comments in here like _the galaxy is not made -- it is there in potential, based on the rules of the system. FD does not have a database of 400 billion stars. They likely only have a database of bodies discovered and scanned. The rest can be created as needed._. I haven't got any hard evidence to make this an answer yet, but procedurally generated as it is discovered seems quite likely.

Comment: I've revised this question, because we usually can't answer "How did game X achieve Y?" Often the exact details are not known by anyone outside the game X development team, and they may be prevented from describing the innards by NDAs. Moreover, it's usually not as helpful a question as it seems. If the Elite folks pulled this off using some tech that you don't have access to, then knowing that doesn't help you solve your problem. But asking "How can *my game* achieve Y?" focuses answers on solutions that will work for you, whether or not they're exactly what "game X" did.

Comment: Elite Dangerous famously *doesn't* store the data.  It's how the original Elite managed to fit 4096 star systems into 360 kilobytes of space.

Comment: I'm with Philipp - don't use a database if you don't have to. **If** you're really determined to use one and its performance is the question here, then this quickly becomes a DB optimization question and not a GameDev one. You said you did a lot of optimization... what does that mean? What data are you storing in which tables? Can you break things out into smaller tables? You certainly don't need to store missiles in there with solar systems! What indexes do you have on your tables? Have you profiled your queries? Are you making lots of separate small queries when one large resultset would do?

Comment: @AC Well, for now I created a database with stars, planets, moons in a typical galaxy shape. I think the details about the optimization are not relevant. But out of curiosity (as I now plan to use Procedural Generation), what better way is there to store large amounts of data, if not a DB? As of "non-static" elements like missiles and ships, they are supposed to be saved in the server cache. Ships will be saved in intervals if they had any change to the DB, or on events like going offline.

Comment: @Battle I just meant that procedural generation is a good way to do this; that way you don't have to store anything (you just recompute it).  Also, that way you get to skip the boring database optimization and focus on making your game ;-)

Comment: @Mark much less than 360kb - it ran on systems which only had 48k available RAM.

Comment: What can the player actually do with these star systems? Can they travel to them? How fast can they travel? There is no way they will visit even ten thousand star systems before they get bored of playing.

Comment: @user253751 - This is a challenge related to making the game good. In general, the game will have a variety of content, and exploration is just one aspect. Others are having star bases, defending/maintaining them, mining, producing, trading, research, and a major focus on combat (PvE and PvP). For that you may want to have a good strategic location. For that you need a sufficiently large world to select one. Guilds/factions may want to have their players' star bases in close proximity. Then you have to account for an unknown number of players, thus scalability.

Comment: The player won't even consider 10000 worlds before selecting one. They'd have to spend Probably should have mentioned that it's multiplayer then: even if each player only looks at 1000 worlds, you might have 1000000 players who each want a different set of 1000 worlds, hence the requirement for so many worlds.

Comment: @user253751 - Well, it's likely most players would visit similar solar systems until they spread out over a sufficiently long distance (assuming the same spawning area). They won't need to consider thousands of solar systems before selecting one. The selection isn't permanent either (station relocation would be possible). The sheer massive size of the galaxy is also there to have in-between space. Distance will be a relevant factor for various things (time, fuel). But I would limit it to ~200-300m solar systems for the initial galaxy.

Comment: @pjc50, 360 KB was the available space on a single-sided, double-density floppy disk.  No sensible developer of the time would load anything into memory that wasn't immediately required.

Comment: There's a great writeup on Frontier Elite II here that might be an interesting read to you: http://www.jongware.com/galaxy1.html

Comment: @Mark yes, but you could play Elite from tape.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The trick Elite likely uses is that they don't pre-generate the whole galaxy and store it in a database. They likely generate most of the galaxy at runtime when it is needed.

I would do this using a pseudorandom but deterministic algorithm which can generate the properties of every object in the galaxy at runtime just from its position.

So when a player zooms into a section of the galaxy, then the galaxy chunk generation algorithm is run, which takes the chunk coordinates as input and outputs a list of stars with position, color and size. Same input always results in the same output, so when another player zooms into the same chunk later, they get the same results. You might have different algorithms for different zoom levels which each take the output of the previous algorithm into account and add more detail to it. So the algorithm on the lowest zoom factor only generates the largest stars (so you can quickly generate a view which shows the whole galaxy at once), and the closer the player zooms into any part of the galaxy, the more additional small stars get generated in that area.

Then, when the player clicks on any of these stars to zoom into its star system, the star system generation algorithm is run. Its input are color, size and galactic position of the star. Its output is a list of planets with their types, sizes and orbital parameters. It too is a deterministic algorithm so it always generates the same planets for the same star.

And then you can do the same thing with planet surfaces, cities on the planet surfaces, houses in those cities and rooms in those houses. So you end up with a galaxy with a level of detail which would take an exorbitant amount of data to store all at once. But you don't need to store it all, because any of that data can be re-calculated on demand.

A really neat tool for procedural generation algorithms like that are noise pattern algorithms like [Simplex Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise) or [Worley Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worley_noise). You can sample them at arbitrary locations to get reproducible results. Another are standard pseudorandom number generators which can be initialized with a seed value and then always generate the same sequence of numbers for the same seed value.

All you really need to store in a database is data which can not actually be re-generated on demand:

- Parts of the galaxy which you want to design by hand
- Changes to the galaxy which are the result of player actions

First you check if any such datasets exist in your database for the requested data, and when they don't, you generate the data using the algorithms.

__

Now you just need to come up with algorithms which generate interesting and varied results and then with game mechanics which provide an engaging and interesting game experience which benefits from all that content variety. I am looking forward to playing what you will come up with.

Comment: Now I want to implement a galaxy generator like that. But I must restrain myself. Starting your game project by making a procedural generation system when you didn't create the actual game yet is a bad idea. You won't yet know what content your game *actually* needs. And when you don't know that, then your procedural generation will end up creating plenty of content which doesn't actually do much to help the game mechanics to shine and instead just result in a bland and boring game experience. *Elite:Dangerous* suffered a lot from that.

Comment: *[No Man's Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Man%27s_Sky)* was infamous for overuse of procedurally generated content resulting in overly repetitive gameplay.

Comment: According to [this](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy#Milky_Way_Galaxy), the Frontier team started with the 160,000 known star systems and then uses a system they developed called [Stellar Forge](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Stellar_Forge) to generate the rest based on first principles of astrophysics theory.

Comment: This is a great answer and very helpful. I am already in the process of learning how to apply Procedural Generation. I think it's indeed a better way to do all of this, and allows me to easily have multiple galaxies with way more solar systems. As of the monotony problem - I already have a possible solution for that. A mix of random factors making solar systems quasi-unique as they peak, and presets that set up a special constellation at baseline, like a resource rich planet dangerously close to a star, or a star emitting excessive amounts of lethal solar flares.

Comment: Take a look at this video, it explains the concepts in Philipp answer in a very simple and very clear way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZY9YE7rZJw

Comment: From what I once read about Elite&co's procedural generation, there's one more bullet point for your "store explicitly" list: a list of exceptions where the procedural results should be discarded because they happen to generate inappropriate content (NSFW system names etc.)

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO I don't see a reason to mention that specifically. Discarding and redoing procedural results which are undesirable (for whatever reason - not just profanity but also simply because they would result in a bad or imbalanced game experience) and can be detected automatically should be part of your procedural generation algorithms. And when you discover one unique result people complain about but which is unlikely to occur a 2nd time, you would fix that by replacing that part of the world manually, which will give you a "part of the galaxy which you designed by hand".

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO - I think Philipp is right. I want to generate rare extreme results and not discard them. After all, my algorithms would have boundaries anyway, so the extreme cases would be where multiple factors are at a peak. As of profanity, I don't think that will be an issue. An object may be called "s5xy", but well, then it's a star/planet/moon with a funny name. And the biggest NSFW thing about games is to play them at work.

Comment: @Battle Well, the worst that could happen is that your algorithm outputs names which happen to match code phrases of political extremists. But when you indeed got a player group of neonazis gathering around the [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_pride)-[14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteen_Words) star cluster (which happens to be shaped kind like a swastika), then you can later troll them by renaming all the stars in it after antifascists and famous people of color.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points that have been made about not actually generating all the data there's another factor:  You can't actually draw 10,000,000 stars.  Nobody has a display that can handle it.  Therefore, there's no need to have 10,000,000 stars loaded.

Select X, Y, Brightness, Color, ID from StarTable Where X > CurrentX - 200ly And X < CurrentX + 200ly And Y > CurrentY - 200ly And Y < CurrentY + 200ly.

Select X, Y, Brightness, Color, ID from BrightStarTable Where X > CurrentX - 2000ly And X < CurrentX + 2000ly And Y > CurrentY - 2000ly And Y < CurrentY + 2000ly.

That will be a tiny fraction of your total stars, but it is sufficient to draw anything you can see out the window of your starship.  I would store all the details on the stars in a separate table accessed by the StarID as you only need those details when examining a particular star.

You can cut the loaded data down even more by having a DimStarTable with an even shorter query range.  Most stars will be in this table.

Another option also comes to mind:  Define a new variable: Sector.  Sector = (int)(x/100ly) + (int)(y/100ly) * 10000.  You load the sector you are in and the 8 adjoining sectors.  The select would run faster.  (Likewise, the bright star table would have 1000ly sectors.)

Comment: The "Select" looks rather troublesome. I'd expect an octree instead.

Comment: @MSalters He said "database".  Assuming there are indexes on X and Y that select should be fast.

Answer (score 1):

Philipp already gave a great answer, but I'll address your question about how Elite Dangerous operates their database.

> Elite Dangerous manages to store the data of 400 billion solar systems and has no issues with loading times, somehow. How can they display many stars in the background? How do they manage to store a lot more data than I already do?

1. Elite Dangerous stores the star map data that isn't procedurally generated on a server, not locally. They presumably have one or more very powerful servers, optimized for big data, with the database always loaded and running. When the player scrolls around the map or visits a new star system, the game client sends a request to the server, the server queries relevant data from the database and sends it back to the game client. Because the database is on a server, it could potentially be many terabytes in size without causing any issues for the players. They probably have very big and expensive servers developed over years by backend specialists, so this approach is unlikely to be feasible for an indie team.
2. Elite Dangerous absolutely has loading times, they just cleverly mask it with in-game mechanics. This is educated guesswork, but based on my play experience I think it works like this:

   1. When you activate the hyperdrive, there's a progress bar while the hyperdrive warms up. I think this is the stage when the game client sends the request for data for the system you're about to jump to. Occasionally, this takes much longer than normal for no explicable reason - probably because the server was slow to respond to the query.
   2. During the actual hyperspace jump, the game is loading/procedurally generating the next star system, including the background skybox, based on the data it received from the server. The animation you see of your ship hurtling through hyperspace is just a very fancy loading screen.

Answer (score -6):

If you have a deterministic algorithm that uses a seed, like how PRNG's work, you can store almost nothing and generate the star's positions on the fly, only keeping those that you currently need.  Think how demoscene demos work.

Comment: This seems to be the same point made in Philipp's existing answer, but with much less detail. Would you consider editing this answer to expand on it?

Comment: @DMGregory No, you have all you need to get started.

Comment: SE's more about contributing and building information. If an answer is effectively saying the same as another, it's not as useful. If the answer was fleshed out a bit to differentiate it from the main answer, it might be more welcome.